# How to run nodejs server as a background task in jenkins and restart the server on autobuild?

Tags: node.js, django, jenkins

I'm currently working on nodejs application. I need to make frequent changes to it. I have a job set up in jenkins which automatically builds if changes are made. The job runs django and node api concurrently as background tasks but severs do not restart after autobuild.

I've tried using nohup , forever start and pm2 start.

commands used -
nohup python3 manage.py runserver **.**.**.**:**** &
pm2 start app.js

How to run django and nodejs servers as background tasks in jenkins and automatically restart if changes are pushed?

Answer (score 0):

PM2 have a flag called `--watch`

You could just do `pm2 start server.js --watch`